# Xamarin.Android apk crashes after building on visualstudioonline

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-devops

We got a Xamarin.Android project and are using visualstudioonline for building our app. When I build locally with my IDE (Visual Studio 2015) the app works as expected in Debug and also in Release mode. I tried to deploy the app directly from Visual Studio (Run) and also to grab the .apk file after a build from the bin directory. Everything works.

Now when I build the app with the build server on visualstudioonline the app instantly crashes when I launch the app on a device. Ive got another app on visualstudioonline with the same settings in my build task and there is no such problem (latest MSBuild version and JDK 8)

I only have the log from logcat because I also get no events, exceptions or crash reports on AppCenter.

The app in the log is called "preon.AndroidApplication"

[Logcat log - whole logcat output](https://gist.github.com/raaaimund/8efe904cb36d9b1e77e4ee11634d71cd)

[Logcat log - where I think the error is located](https://gist.github.com/raaaimund/6631219c1215c7a547efda0ec34ad07d)

Comment: What is in the logcat output **prior** to the `Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)` at the beginning of the output you posted?

Comment: This is the logcat output prior my output in my question: https://gist.github.com/raaaimund/196e1c7f7a0315dbce7ed5b98c924aa7

Comment: Do you have `Shared Runtime` enabled in your build (`Release`?) configuration that you are building?

Comment: Nope, ive disabled Shared Runtime in my configuration (only in Debug its enabled, but I build for Release config)

Comment: What's the result if you build/publish the app through command line manually? Which agent you used? Is it a private agent? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive (set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)?

Comment: If I build/publish the app in Visual Studio 2015 everything is working fine in Debug and Release mod.
I use the default hosted agent queue in vso - it is no private agent. The log files with system.debug=true are on my [onedrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_GhtccBl11tNlwZqr2zl5KNDw__w)

Comment: Looks like it could be related to OS versioning, It might be worth double checking your minimum build requirements and the simulated device being used on the build server. You often see similar SIGABRT errors on devices running pre-lollipop.

Comment: Now I tried using a private build agent on my development machine and this build is fine - i can install the .apk and launch the app - everything is working fine. So maybe there is an issue with the hosted build agent on vsts?

Comment: So, you just change to private agent without other changes, it works fine? If so, the issue related to the environment, you compare the logs.

Comment: Yes I just changed to a private agent (which I installed on my development machine) and now it works fine. So yes the issue is related to the environment. I will compare the logs on the weekend and will let you know if I found something.

Comment: Did you find anything? I have the same problem, using the windows-2019 hosted agent my app crashes at runtime when I click a button on the app, but using the vs2017 agent, it works fine

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, wondering if he found the reason and what difference on the hosted env that caused the carash

Comment: I did not find the reason, to be honest. I left everything unchanged and only switched the agent to a private one. After some time I switched back to an Azure DevOps agent and everything worked as expected.